# UE4: Actor disappears after play is hit

Tags: c++, graphics, unreal-engine4, game-development

I am using Unreal Engine version 4.25. I have created an actor and placed it on a blank template. The actor is visible in the editor but becomes invisible once the play button is hit. I am trying to move the object in circles with my code.

Here's the code:

MyActor.cpp

```
#include "MyActor.h"

// Sets default values
AMyActor::AMyActor()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    Dimensions = FVector(10, 0, 0);
    AxisVector = FVector(1, 0, 0);
    Location   = FVector(1, 0, 0);
    Multiplier = 50.f;

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMyActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void AMyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);



    // Updates the angle of the object
    AngleAxis += DeltaTime * Multiplier;

    if (AngleAxis >= 360.0f)
    {
        AngleAxis = 0;
    }

    //Rotates around axis
    FVector RotateValue = Dimensions.RotateAngleAxis(AngleAxis, AxisVector);

    Location.X += RotateValue.X;
    Location.Y += RotateValue.Y;
    Location.Z += RotateValue.Z;

    SetActorLocation(Location, false, 0, ETeleportType::None);

}
```

MyActor.h

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "MyActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class ROBOTEURS_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AMyActor();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // declare our float variables
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = Movement)
        float AngleAxis;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = Movement)
        FVector Dimensions;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = Movement)
        FVector AxisVector;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = Movement)
        FVector Location;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = Movement)
        float Multiplier;

};
```

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Your actor has no components, let alone any renderable components. what are you expecting to see in game?

Comment: @Rotem, I'm completely new to this. Can you tell me what to look up or please explain?

Comment: What are you seeing in the editor that you expect to be seeing during a game?Your actor has no visual representation, e.g. a mesh component of some kind.

Comment: I am seeing my object in the editor. I expect the object to move around in circles during the game.

Comment: What does your object look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it, I did not create a mesh:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30XEdBoPw6c

I added the following:

.cpp

```
AMyActor::AMyActor()
{
    ...
    Root = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("Root"));
    RootComponent = Root;

    Mesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Mesh"));
    Mesh->AttachTo(Root);

    ...
}
```

.h

```
public: 
    ...

    UPROPERTY()
        USceneComponent* Root;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
        UStaticMeshComponent* Mesh;
    ...
```